# to suffer vs to hurt ("people always hurt/suffer during wars")

Tags: word-choice

> A lot of innocent people always **hurt/suffer** during wars.

Are both verbs can be used in that context? If it is so, could you explain please the difference? "Hurt" is more about physical pain, but "suffer" is more about mental pain, right?

Comment: Suffer is the better word choice here, because it shows the intensity of privation during wartime (think rationing, among other things). Hurt makes it sound rather trivial.

Comment: As FelinusRex says, though you might say "...people **are** always hurt during wars", meaning they are injured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, either can be used for either mental or physical pain. The use here is intransitive ("people hurt," which is different than "people hurt other people"). If the use were transitive ("innocent people **are hurt** during wars"), it would *suggest* physical injury rather than mental, but there's still nothing wrong with choosing "hurt" for mental pain, especially if the context makes it clear. For instance, "A lot of innocent people are always hurt during wars, not only bodily, but with wounds of mind and spirit that are just as injurious."

Note, "suffer" can't be used transitively, at least not with this meaning. You can say "He doesn't suffer fools lightly," in which *suffer* is more of a synonym of *endure* or *tolerate*.

Comment: Btw. Except in "I am hurting all over", the intransitive form - _I hurt, I am hurting, America is hurting_  - is rarely heard in the UK.